# Using Angular 5 Form Group and Array to update data

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using Angular FormGroup and FormArray to allow a user to add a new instance of a FormGroup and to edit current Forms.  I am having trouble figuring out how to update the data.  See here..https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-patch-jfb9f8?file=app/app.component.html

I am able to append a new instance of the form on click of the "Add" button, but how should the `updateBins()` function work when saving the data (either in a new form or added form). Struggling with how to link the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just need some changes:

1) push FormGroup to FormArray

```
this.binsFormArray.controls.push(this.createBin(newBin));
```

should be

```
this.binsFormArray.push(this.createBin(newBin));
```

2)   Display form value

```
<pre>{{ bins | json }}</pre>
```

should be

```
<pre>{{ binsForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks haifzhan, that is very helpful but how do I also use a separate function (click on the update button) to store the new FormArrays to my bin Array?

Comment: to update your `bins` Array, you can get last `FormGroup` from `FormArray` and use `formGroupItem.get('id').value` to access the id control, but I don't think you need update your local `bins` array. you can access it via `binsForm.value`